# Getting error while running project in xcode 6.1.1 with "FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h" not found

Tags: xcode, facebook-sdk-3.0, osx-yosemite

Getting error while running project in xcode 6.1.1 with "FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h" not found though it is working fine in xcode 6.1.

I got this issue when i sifted to new mac mini with Yosemite O.S.

Please help me to get out of this issue.

Thanks for any help.